# R, subtract a value from the corresponding and following values in a numerical column each time conditions are met in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

Below, I have a data frame with consecutive values in the first column (col1). When a 'q' is encountered in the second column (col2), 1 has to be subtracted from the corresponding value in column 1 and all the other values following in column 1. When a second q is encountered, again, an additional 1 has to be subtracted from the corresponding value in column 1 and all the other values following in column 1. etc. 
Note, every new data frame has different values in both column 1 and 2. I wondered which approach should be right? I tried subsetting and if else statements. The following code fails to produce consecutive numbering.

```
df$col3 = ifelse(df$mut!="q",df$col1, ifelse(grepl("q",df$col2),(df$col1-1),0) )
```

**example dataset**

```
col1 = c(115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124) 
col2 = c('s1','s2','s3', "q", "s4", "q", "s5", "q", "q", "s6")
df = data.frame(col1, col2)

col1 col2
115  s1
116  s2
117  s3
118  q
119  s4
120  q
121  s5
122  q
123  q
124  s6
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
115  s1   115
116  s2   116
117  s3   117
118  q    117
119  s4   118
120  q    118
121  s5   119
122  q    119
123  q    119
124  s6   120
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` which accumulates the cases where `df$col2 == "q"` and subtract this form `df$col1`.

```
df$col3 <- df$col1 - cumsum(df$col2 == "q")
#   col1 col2 col3
#1   115   s1  115
#2   116   s2  116
#3   117   s3  117
#4   118    q  117
#5   119   s4  118
#6   120    q  118
#7   121   s5  119
#8   122    q  119
#9   123    q  119
#10  124   s6  120
```